# How to setup and use camel cxfrs in pure java

Tags: apache-camel

http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html describes how to use camel-cxf to create or consume restservices however the configuration (server or client) is only shown in xml.

So how to set it up in pure java?

Comment: Check out the examples from the 2nd edition of the "Camel in Action" book: https://github.com/DariusX/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter10

Comment: if u post an example as an answer it will most likely be accepted :-)

Comment: Unfortunately there are no examples to use camel's cxf rs CLIENT bean in java there.